# Standard Visitor Visa for a British National

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

Okay, this is a very weird question.

My son is Bolivian, and we're applying for his British citizenship. Most likely, that will arrive before we are due to travel to the UK. However, in order to be in the UK when we need to be, we likely won't have time to get his British passport. So, my question is - is it possible to get a visitor visa for him once he's a British national? Or is there a way to get into the country without a British passport? He'll have a Bolivian passport.

Bolivian citizens can go to the Republic of Ireland without a visa, could we travel up, apply for the passport, and then live in the Republic until his passport arrives? I know this is a very obscure question.

Comment: By "British national" do you mean "British citizen"?  There are a few types of British nationality that do not confer right of abode.

Comment: Sorry, yes. He'll be a British citizen. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of law, a UK national is not supposed to get a UK visa.  A dual citizen child that the UK doesn't know about might be able to get one, but in your case the UK knows about your child's nationality.

Your child can certainly enter Ireland with a Bolivian passport and then, assuming your child is a British citizen, can travel entirely legally to the UK without a UK passport or visa.  In other words, yes, you can live in Ireland until the passport arrives, but you don't have to.

Comment: There's going to be the usual passport/visa check during check-in or boarding, though, which is probably going to be a problem. Unless you mean crossing over the ROI/NI border-which-doesn't-really-exist-or-does-it-or-maybe-it-will-be-back-or-maybe-not.

Comment: @jcaron Aer Lingus, at least, says that for flights between the Republic of Ireland and the UK "citizens of Ireland and Britain under the age of 16 don’t need a photo ID if travelling with their parent/guardian."  Source: https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/passports-and-visas/travel-to-from-britain/.  Whatever happens on the land border, they won't be requiring passports for citizens of Ireland or the UK.

Comment: @phoog okay, so logistically then - once his citizenship comes through, we could fly into Dublin with a flight out for some time within those three months we can be in Ireland, and just drive up to the North and apply for the passport there? Is it important we fly out of Dublin again within those three months so it doesn't look like he's overstaying?

Comment: @SarahLouise You don't have to wait for his UK citizenship. Under the EU free movement directive, your son can *remain in Ireland indefinitely with you* even while he is not a British citizen. To stay for longer than three months you could be asked to show that you are working or that you have sufficient means to support yourself during your stay. This could change at some point as the UK leaves the EU, but it probably won't change right away. Once he is a British citizen, he can travel to the UK without a British passport and stay as long as you like.

Comment: @SarahLouise He can also apply for the UK passport in Ireland: https://www.passport.service.gov.uk/overseas/information/ireland/first/child/bolivia

Comment: @phoog okay, but I live in the North, so we wouldn’t come back until he’s got UK citizenship cus we’d have to live over the border and that just doesn’t sound like much fun!

Comment: @SarahLouise of course, if that makes the most sense for you, you should do it.  I just want to make sure you know what is possible (you could actually stay in any EU country other than the UK, if for some reason you had to leave Bolivia). You may want to be prepared to prove your family relationship *at the Irish border,* so he can enter as a family member of an EU citizen and not be subject to the time limit normally placed on non-EU visitors.

Comment: @SarahLouise let me clarify: as a matter of law he should not be subject to that limit in any case, but asserting his right to free movement at the border would reduce the chance of some sort of administrative trouble arising from his entry being recorded with the Bolivian passport.  However, if such a problem ever did arise, it should be possible to resolve it immediately by showing that he is a British citizen or alternatively that you are a British citizen and he is your son.

Comment: @phoog but a lot of this changes with Brexit, right? I don't have my Irish passport yet, though being born in the North I do have a claim to Irish citizenship too.

Comment: @phoog I'm hoping leaving Bolivia urgently won't be necessary, but who knows. It's definitely good to have this information.

Comment: @SarahLouise I'm not sure what will change with Brexit, but if the UK leaves with a deal, free movement will continue for a year or two.  If it leaves without a deal, free movement could end immediately.  Much has been written on the status of Irish citizens in the UK after the end of free movement (more privileged than that of other EU citizens), but I haven't seen much on the status of UK citizens in Ireland.  On the other hand, as you were born in NI, I suppose the possibility of your asserting Irish citizenship would also imply a possibility of your son being an Irish citizen.

Comment: @SarahLouise Brits and Irish will retain full right of abode in each other's countries, even in case of no-deal. The EU has no say in this.